# Elixir MapSet vs Enum.member?

Tags: elixir

I need to keep only unique values and I am confused which data structure should I use. Later on I will only read the whole data structure.

- One way is to use `MapSet` which will contain only unique elements.
- The second approach is to check each time with `Enum.member?` whether an item is already there - but I can easily guarantee that through `MapSet`.

I am not sure which approach is better to use in such scenario. Which is more efficient, and which is better practice?

Comment: `Enum.member?` is a function that can operate on a number of different data structure like Lists and Maps. `Enum.member?` is not a data structure itself. That being said, the `MapSet` sounds fine for your purposes...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you keep your data in a `MapSet`, then `Enum.member?` will in fact call `MapSet.member?` underneath, so you will have all advantages of `MapSet`. You can see the relevant protocol implementation [here](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/map_set.ex#L372).

Answer (score 1):

I think you're confusing datastructures and [protocols](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/protocols.html). MapSet is a datastructure (and a module) that implements the [`Enumerable`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enumerable.html) protocol. You can call [`Enum.member/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#member?/2) on a MapSet, but it's not necessary:

```elixir
mapset =
  MapSet.new()
  |> MapSet.put(1)
  |> MapSet.put(2)
  |> MapSet.put(2)
  |> MapSet.put(3)
  |> MapSet.put(3)
  |> MapSet.put(3)

Enum.join(mapset, ",")
```

Output:

```elixir
"1,2,3"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you already have datastructure with duplicates use [Enum.uniq/1](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#uniq/1).

Example:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4] |> Enum.uniq
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```